# Mongoose Object/Mixed Schema not saving additions to object

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Model in mongoose with a field named items, I've tried setting the type to Object and mongoose.Mixed but whatever but I can't add to the object. When I do the following, it just overwrites the previous item_id (even though the item_id is different). Adding to the object works because when I console.log it before saving the new item_id is there, but when I save it just overwrites the previous value I saved. I'm probably missing something very simple but can't seem to figure it out.

```
var items = (order.items) ?? {}
items[item_id] = {product_title: product_title, total: total}
order.items = items

order.save()
```

I've also tried

```
order.items[item_id] = {product_title: product_title, total: total}
order.save()
```

Schemas I've tried

```
items : { type: mongoose.Mixed },
```

and

```
items : { type: Object },
```

Comment: Note the function is much more complex than this (but I have to redact) and other values I set in the function to order save fine. I also have a catch statement after save and there are no errors

Comment: Can we see the schema?

Comment: @PsiKai I added them to the post, thank you.